# image and price from a entity extension ( product ) are not shown in own storefront module, but the other informations are shown

Tags: twig, shopware

similar to this question [in sw-entity-many-to-many-select in a own admin module product variants without names are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833377/in-sw-entity-many-to-many-select-in-a-own-admin-module-product-variants-without) i want to display the assigned products on my storefront page, like it is discribed here (in a tab with `{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/product/card/box-standard.html.twig' with {'product': product} %}` ): https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle/storefront . This works, but the image and the price is not loaded, but the other informations are shown. Has anybody an idea why or what is missing?

See: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b26hS.png)

Comment: Can you share the code how you load the products that you want to display? In the docs it is described in this chapter: https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/indepth-guide-bundle/storefront#loading-the-association
It looks like you need to additionally include the `product.cover` and `product.prices` associations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. I add the products over:

`$criteria->addAssociation('products')`

When i change it to: 

`$criteria->addAssociation('products.cover');`

the images were loaded. But when i add
`$criteria->addAssociation('products.cover');
$criteria->addAssociation('products.prices');`

the prices don't loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of loading the product with the "normal" product repository you can use the `sales_channel.product.repository` repository instead.
The sales-channel repositories load the entities with all necessary associations, so you don't have to load those associations yourself.

For details you can check the `\Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductDefinition` definition, in that class the additional associations and fields are configured that are loaded by the sales channel repository.

Keep in mind that the product sales channel repository implements the `\Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Entity\SalesChannelRepositoryInterface` instead of the `\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface` and thus the search method requires a SalesChannelContext instead of the Context.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the way over the SalesChannel - Product - Repository is the best way to get all necessary data. 

Within my own controller i can get the assigned products to my entity over `$entityEntry->getProducts()->getElements()` and based on the product id(s), a Criteria and a EqualsAnyFilter and the SalesChannel - Product - Repository i get the products with the additional associations.